# Accessing parentElement properties via event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a div which I called quote_div and is the parentElement. It contains two `input type="number"` elements, a `<label>` element which I called r_lbl (variable name) and another `<label>` element called r_position (so that's four elements in one div).

I put an event listener on the div so that when either `input type="number"` element is changed I can perform a calculation.

`quote_div.addEventListener("change", calculateCost);`

Now I'm trying to access the r_position element on the div using the event trigger e (which is parsed to calculateCost(e) function) but i get an undefined error which is strange because I've predefined the value for r_position.

```
console.log("li element position: " + e.target.parentElement.r_position.value);
```

Is it not possible to do things this way? If so, what have I not understood?

Comment: Is that so? I thought target referred to the input type="number" element which triggered the event.

Comment: `undefined` is not an error, it's a value. `e.currentTarget` contains a reference to the element which the event was attached to. However, it's not clear, what you mean with "_element called r_position_", does that element have _r\_position_ as `id` or `name`? If that's the case, you better to use an appropriate DOM getter to get the reference instead of the direct dot notation. It would be easier to answer the question, if you'd provide an example of the HTML instead of describing it.

Comment: @Teemu I created r_position dynamically in one function: var r_position = document.createElement("label"). So r_position is the variable name itself. I"m thinking along the lines of java in using dot notation to access things this way, I was just not sure its possible or not since I was getting the value of undefined

Comment: Ah, okay. Then it is not a property of the parent element, it's just a name of a JS variable. Use `e.currentTarget.querySelector('label')` to get a reference to the label, then retrieve `textContent`, labels don't have value. (Or `.querySelectorAll('label')[1]`, if the target label is not the first label in the div.)

Comment: @Teemu, that makes sense. I thought using .value would give the text content in the case of labels. I appreciate the insight

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your HTML structure, you could use [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling) or [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling):

```js
const div = document.getElementById('quote_div');

div.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const target = e.target;  
  const label = target.previousElementSibling;
  
  console.log(label.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div id="quote_div">
  <label class="r_lbl" for="input1">Label 1</label>
  <input id="input1" type="number" />
  
  <label class="r_position" for="input2">Label 2</label>
  <input id="input2" type="number" />
</div>
```

Otherwise, you could use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) from the parent `<div>` using an `id`, `class`, `name` or any other selector:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('quote_div');

div.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const div = e.target.parentElement;  
  const label1 = div.querySelector('.r_lbl');
  const label2 = div.querySelector('.r_position');
  
  console.log(label1.innerText, label2.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div id="quote_div">
  <label class="r_lbl" for="input1">Label 1</label>
  <input id="input1" type="number" />
  
  <label class="r_position" for="input2">Label 2</label>
  <input id="input2" type="number" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Danzinger thanks for the link to NonDocumentTypeChildNode, I was not aware it existed but it may just be what I need.